# How to check if delimter is multi character in python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to check if the delimiter of a file is multicharacter. There are cases where user provides separator of a file with multiple characters. Based on the character i wanted to decide the logic to read/write into a file. From spark 3.0 multi character is supported unfortunately we are still < 3.0

```
separator="|,"
if len(separator)>1:
    headers ="col1|,col2|,col3"
    head = headers.split(separator)
    df = sc.textFile("/hdfsData/fileanme.txt").map(lambda x: x.split("|,")).toDF(head)
else:
    df = sc.read.csv("/hdfsData/fileanme.txt",sep=separator,header=True)
```

but in case of separator like \t this logic wont work

right now i am planning to do something like this

```
if len(separator)>1 and separator != "\t":
    headers ="col1|,col2|,col3"
    head = headers.split(separator)
    df = sc.textFile("/hdfsData/fileanme.txt").map(lambda x: x.split("|,")).toDF(head)
else:
    df = sc.read.csv("/hdfsData/fileanme.txt",sep=separator,header=True)
```

Is there a better way to implement this multicharacter separator in pyspark?

Comment: `'\t'` is a single character. Why treat it like the multi-char ones?

Comment: \t is a tab, not multiple characters.

Comment: Yup! My bad! The above logic worked well for all delimiters